# Meaning of symbol "$y\nearrow x$" in CDF Limit

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, notation

Could somebody explain the meaning of "$y\nearrow x$"?

> $F_X$ is right continuous, that is, for any $x$, $\lim_{y \nearrow x} F_X (y) = F_X(x)$.

Comment: Right continuous should be limit as $y$ approaches $x$ from above. I've not seen the arrow notation, but it seems if the arrow goes up and to the right it would mean $y$ approaches $x$ from below, which isn't correct for right continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usually writes "$y_n\nearrow x$" (resp. "$y_n\searrow x$"), or "$y_n\uparrow y$" (resp. "$y_n\downarrow x$"), to indicate an ascending (resp. descending) sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n=x$.

I think "$y\nearrow x$" should be a placeholder for the more common "$y\to x^-$" ($y$ approaches $x$ from the left), due to the fact that: $$\lim_{y\to x^-}f(y)=L\iff \forall\text{ non-constant }\ y_n\nearrow x,\ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)=L$$ This, however, leaves me a bit puzzled, because I would have called that property [left-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Directional_and_semi-continuity).

> In fact, the context strongly suggests that the author meant "$y\to x^+$". Personally, though, I would have written "$\lim\limits_{y\searrow x}$" instead. Perhaps it was a typo.

Comment: Yes, and since if $F_X$ is the usual notation for the cumulative for random variable $X$ the continuity should be generally from the right, not left,

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, a bit odd, in fact. Perhaps it's a typo in the source...